# What's the maximum size of a USB descriptor?

Tags: usb, usb-device

I would imagine it has some theoretical limit right? I'm just curious so I can gauge how many endpoints a device can have based on the space used for all the other configurations. Or is it limited only by the hardware (i.e. the size of a microcontroller's flash memory)?

Comment: This question can not be answered in its current form.  What is a "USB descriptor"?  Is this something in the USB protocol, something per device in a USB host, something per endpoint per device in a USB host, something per endpoint in a USB device, etc?  There are many things that could be "descriptors".  Some like the device descriptor, configuration descriptor, and interface descriptor are even defined as such in the spec.  -1 for sloppiness to the point of gibberish.

Comment: See Chapter 9 of the USB specification: http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/ (usb_31_031114.zip, size 29.8 MB) Note that USB 3 "superspeed" mode adds several new types of descriptors above and beyond the standard USB 2.0 descriptors that describe and configure a device's capabilities. Each USB endpoint is a FIFO buffer for transferring data. Having too many FIFO streams can make a design difficult to understand, debug, and maintain. Perhaps you're asking about the FIFO depth, or the block transfer throughput?

Comment: @Mark: The point is we don't know what the OP is asking, which is why this mess needs to be closed or fixed.

Comment: @OlinLathrop yes I agree, OP needs to read the spec and clarify.

Answer (score 4):

For the configuration descriptor the wTotalLength field is 2 byte, that would indicate a 64 KB maximum. But you cannot have more than 32 endpoints in a single USB device - there are only four bits for the ep number for each direction (in/out).

Comment: No, you can not possibly know this from the question.  There are many "descriptors" in USB, and very few of them are exactly 2 bytes in size.  Even if this is true in some specific hardware, without qualifying it to that hardware, this answer is just plain wrong.

Comment: The configuration descriptor is the one with the all the interface and endpoint descriptors summed up in the wTotalLength field.